# Obtaining the URI argument within a registered uap:protocol executable

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, msix

I have a C# WPF application and I've referenced that inside a MSIX package.
I've also registered a URI protocol within the Package.appxmanifest of my MSIX package the following way:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol" EntryPoint="AppLauncher"
                    Executable="AppLauncher\AppLauncher.exe">
                    <uap:Protocol Name="app-drive" >
                    </uap:Protocol>
</uap:Extension>
```

The goal is when I type `app-drive:\\C:\test.txt` into the file explorer or a browser for my executable to launch and within it I want to have the following string accessible  `C:\test.txt`.

After I install my MSIX package and enter that string anywhere, my program launches correctly but that argument is nowhere to be found.

Ways I've tried to obtain it so far:

1.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 // args[0] contains "-ServerName:App.AppXd****.mca" string
}
```

2. `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`
3. `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)`

All of these contain only the string "-ServerName:App.AppXd****.mca" as a first argument.

Note that I cannot use `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs()` since my application is not UWP.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
Found the solution. Turns out in order for the parameter to be passed to the executable the EntryPoint has to be `EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication"`

Comment: Hi,@Milen Dimitrov.Has your problem been solved? If so, you could post your solution and click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out in order for the parameter to be passed to the executable the EntryPoint has to be EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication".